# How to read heart rate value from polar device using evothings phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to read heart rate data from polar h7 heart rate monitor device? I'm using evothings phonegap plugin  for android. I am able to read service data which include a list of characteristics, handle values. But how to read heart rate value?

```
// ..
{
    "type": 0,
    "uuid": "0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
    "handle": 3,
    "characteristics": [
      {
        "permissions": 0,
        "writeType": 2,
        "properties": 16,
        "uuid": "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
        "handle": 13,
        "descriptors": [
          {
            "permissions": 0,
            "uuid": "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
            "handle": 24
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "permissions": 0,
        "writeType": 2,
        "properties": 2,
        "uuid": "00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
        "handle": 14,
        "descriptors": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }, // ...
```

Calling `evothings.ble.enableNotification(1, 13, ..)` is giving `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Polar H7 follows the Heart Rate Profile specification. Of interest is the [heart_rate_measurement](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) characteristic, which has UUID 2a37 and can be seen in your list.

Calling `evothings.ble.enableNotification` is only half of what you need to do. You must also call `evothings.ble.writeDescriptor(1, 24, new Uint8Array([1,0]), ...)` to actually start the notification.

If notification fails, you can use `readDescriptor()` to poll.